# Admin Custom Menu Editor Disappeared

Tags: menus

The custom menu editor on my site has disappeared. It used to be under the Appearance menu. Any idea where to find it, or how to fix this problem?I have registered and init the menu properly in theme function.
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors displayed? If not, are errors surpressed?  One way to check is to view the page source and scroll to the bottom, if there is an error that stopped execution it should be noted there.  Also, in **wp-config.php** set the constant `WP_DEBUG` to `true` (this is always a good idea if you are developing).

Comment: @DavidGard WP_DEBUG is enabled already..I have doubt on custom post type(news)cause it showing page menu widget on leftside.is there any code for custom post type to add it on custom menu editor..

Comment: It should be added automatically, and the fact it is not suggests that your error is occuring there.

Comment: You should add the code where you register your menus in your functions.php, or better the whole functions.php code, and also add the code of the template where you are loading your menu. Also it may be some plugins conflict, try disabling all your plugins.